# Loading Google Visualizations via AJAX in jQueryUI tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, google-visualization

I'm trying to use jQueryUI tabs, loading the Tabs via AJAX.

The problem I'm having is with Google Visualizations placed on those tabs -- they don't appear when retrieved via AJAX.

I've setup a simple demonstration:

http://htmlto.com/ui/index.php is the tab page. Tab 1 should load the page seen here: http://htmlto.com/ui/tab1.php

But, it doesn't. I've seen similar solutions to this problem that involve altering the AJAX call, except, my AJAX calls are part of the jQueryUI, so I need a solution that plays well with their setup.

I'll be loading many different, dynamically generated visualizations; the data populating needs to take place on the tab, rather than the footer of the main page, otherwise the load time will be untenable.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pages that will be used as tabs should not have HTML, HEAD or BODY tags. I'm pretty sure they should just exist as raw HTML.

**EDIT**

Okay, here's what the `index.php` HEAD section should look like (the rest of the page remains the same):

```
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ui/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script> 
    <link type="text/css" href="/ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                ajaxOptions: {
                    error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                        $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['annotatedtimeline'] });   
    </script> 
<title></title> 
</head>
```

And here's what `lazarus.php` should look like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
     data.addColumn('number', 'Sold Pencils');
     data.addColumn('string', 'title1');
     data.addColumn('string', 'text1');
     data.addColumn('number', 'Sold Pens');
     data.addColumn('string', 'title2');
     data.addColumn('string', 'text2');
     data.addRows([
      [new Date(2008, 1, 1), 30000, undefined, undefined, 40645, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2008, 1, 2), 14045, undefined, undefined, 20374, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2008, 1, 3), 55022, undefined, undefined, 50766, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2008, 1, 4), 75284, undefined, undefined, 14334, 'Out of Stock', 'Ran out of stock on pens at 4pm'],
      [new Date(2008, 1, 5), 41476, 'Bought Pens', 'Bought 200k pens', 66467, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2008, 1, 6), 33322, undefined, undefined, 39463, undefined, undefined]
    ]);

     var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     chart.draw(data, { displayAnnotations: true });
 </script>

<div id='chart_div' style='width: 700px; height: 240px;'></div>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Work For me

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?ext.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {


    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Work',     11],
        ['Eat',      2],
        ['Commute',  2],
        ['Watch TV', 2],
        ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Tasks', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Works',     12],
        ['Eats',      20],
        ['Commutes',  21],
        ['Watch TVs', 12],
        ['Sleeps',    17]
    ]);
    var options = {'title':'Score Chart',
        'width':600,
        'height':300};



    $(".tabs a[title='content_2']").click()
    $(".tabs a[title='content_1']").click()

    var chart = new      google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));


    chart.draw(data, options);


    var chart1= new      google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));


    chart1.draw(data1, options);

}





// When the document loads do everything inside here ...
$(document).ready(function(){

    // When a link is clicked
    $("a.tab").click(function () {


        // switch all tabs off
        $(".active").removeClass("active");

        // switch this tab on
        $(this).addClass("active");

        // slide all content up
        $(".content").slideUp();

        // slide this content up
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#"+content_show).slideDown();

    });

});
</script>


<div id="tabbed_box_1" class="tabbed_box">
<br />
<div class="tabbed_area">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" title="content_1" class="tab active">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="content_2" class="tab">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="content_3" class="tab">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content_1" class="content">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content_2" class="content">
        <div id="chart1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content_3" class="content">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```