# Loading Google Visualizations for core charts via AJAX in jQueryUI tabs

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui, google-visualization

[Loading Google Visualizations via AJAX in jQueryUI tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363875/loading-google-visualizations-via-ajax-in-jqueryui-tabs)

the link above is a similar doubt i have that is i need to use the google Visualization core charts with jqueryui tabs with  ajax first it was not all working i had the same problem but with the solution provided in the link it worked partially it works perfectly for the Visualization chart provide in that example but not with the core charts that is column or pie charts is there some thing different i have to with those charts

the index page contains this script

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script> 
    $(function() {
    $("#switch").tabs({
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                ui.panel.html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " + "If this wouldn't be a demo."
                );
            });
        }
    });
}); //for swicthes  
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
```

and the ajax page contains

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

```
 <div id='chart_div' style='width: 700px; height: 240px;'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.  Changing the javascript in my ajax page to this cracked it:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
  ['2004',  1000,      400],
  ['2005',  1170,      460],
  ['2006',  660,       1120],
  ['2007',  1030,      540]
]);

var options = {
  title: 'Company Performance',
  hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
</script>
```

i.e. remove the callback and take out the drawChart function